# Hang on JWT auth in Jenkins Create Scratch Org stage on OSX

Tags: salesforcedx, jenkins, ci

I have followed the steps in the Salesforce Developer page to setup Jenkins for SFDX CI build.

It always hangs on the task:

```
rc = sh returnStatus: true, script: "${toolbelt}/sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid ${CONNECTED_APP_CONSUMER_KEY} --username ${HUB_ORG} --jwtkeyfile ${jwt_key_file} --setdefaultdevhubusername --instanceurl ${SFDC_HOST}"
```

I also set the environment variable SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN = true to avoid hanging when calling auth.

Does anyone have the same problem?  Please share your thoughts and experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I declare the property on top of the page:
def SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN = true

This solved the problem.